# What does the "items" attribute do?

Tags: mario-kart-ds

The item attribute (below Speed, Acceleration, Handling, etc.) 'Items' has been bugging me a bit when I am picking my vehicle.

It seems that either the Item bar is filled 33% of the way, 66% of the way, or 100% of the bar.

I know it decides how many mushrooms you get in Time Trial mode, but does it do anything outside of that? I'm having trouble still figuring out what purpose it serves.

Comment: I haven't personally tested it, but I always thought that it improved your chances of getting useful items, and not just bloopers 24/7

Comment: I was under that impression too, but staying first place with consistent green shell after green shell isn't exactly very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the number of mushrooms you get in time trials, the higher the kart's item rating the better your chances to get 'useful' items - better chances at tripple bananas/shells and bob-oms vs fake item boxes and single bananas/shells when in first place, and better chances at things like stars and lightning bolts vs bloopers and mushrooms the further behind you are. How much better the odds are exactly, I can't say.

I also seem to recall that a better item stat would slightly reduce the duration of the effects of items used against you (less time spinning out/bouncing), as well as slightly increasing the positive effects of items you use (mushrooms give a slightly bigger boost, stars/bullet bills last a bit longer). However, I have not found many reliable sources to support this, so it may be observational bias on my part.